# ViewBag Data In Javascript/Ajax not passed in correctly

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script.

```
<script>
$("#sendMSG").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        dataType: "JSon",
        data: { "Email": '@ViewBag.Email' },

        success: function (data) { 
             document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = data.Message;},
        error: console.log("It did not work"),
    });
});
</script>
```

Examining the frames source, I get the following 
"Email": 'mdabsk@vsd.com' },

Which to me means it is retrieving it. however when i call the following controller

```
public JsonResult ThankYou(string Email)
{
}
```

it returns me a null value. If you have any ideas on why this might not be working, or require more explanation/code, please let me know and I will gladly provide it.

Thanks

EDIT:

Orignal form code for submitting my other information

```
 [[Form_SmsPhone]]
  <form action="\Controller\Action" id="smsPhone" method="post">
  [[/Form_SmsPhone]]
    [[Block_Sms]]
    <div class="input-append">
        <input id="phonenumber" style="width: 115px;" name="phonenumber"       type="text">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Send"   id="sendMsg">Send</button>
    </div>
    <p id ="Output"></p>
    [[/Block_Sms]]
  [[Form_End]]
    </form>
  [[/Form_End]]
```

Comment: dont put the `'@ViewBag.Email'`, it's just `@ViewBag.Email`

Comment: @AnnArbor87: Wrong.  That will create a Javascript syntax error

Comment: How are your calling the action `ThankYou`? jQuery request seems to be calling some action `Action` of some controller `Controller`.

Comment: Without the '' it will be rendered as data: { "Email": someemail@email.com } which isn't valid json so the '' would be required.

Comment: I never pass the data like that and it works

Comment: Are you sure that you set `ViewBag.Email` value in the GET action of this screen ?

Comment: Unforunately changing this does not solve the problem :(

Comment: Hmm if you debug it.. it goes through that controller but it has null `Email`?

Comment: Can you see the email address displayed correctly in the source of your page after loading?

Comment: I am positive the ViewBag.Email value is within the get action, I have it passed throughout my html code elsewhere. I am also sure that this action works as I have passed in other data with it also, which is being called correctly.

Comment: @alapatag yes that's correct, I'm positive my script is right also, since I pass in other data(which i removed for length purposes)
This is the only viewbag data I'm trying to pass in, as the other information comes from a form i fill out.

Comment: Try setting your content type to be "application/json".

Comment: That other data from the form - is it merged into request? If yes - how?

Comment: @Andrei data: { "phonenumber": $("#phone").val(), "Email": '@ViewBag.Email' }, Full code looks like that for data

Comment: Do you have any routes defined that have email as a variable? Such as {controller}/{action}/{email}. I have found this can cause problems with parameters or properties in model bound objects that have the same name but different or same case.

Comment: Aside from changing your `@Url.Action(...)` line, I put your code verbatim into a new MVC4 project and it worked fine.  Is there something else you're not telling us?

Comment: And how does the actual action look like? Also `sendMSG` is something worth attention - I believe this is a button that posts the form, is it? Anyway I think you should update post with such info - it might be relevant.

Comment: @DSlagle I've also tried to rename the variable from "Email" to other random things with no luck.

Comment: Originally I have the following 

[[Form_SmsPhone]]
 <form action="\Controller\Action" id="SMS" method="post">
[[/Form_SmsPhone]]
        [[Block_Sms]]
        <div class="input-append">
   <input id="phonenumber" style="width: 115px;" name="phonenumber" type="text">
   <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Send" id="sendMsg">Send</button>
     </div>
        <p id ="Output"></p>
        [[/Block_Sms]]
[[Form_End]]
    </form>
[[/Form_End]]

with script exactly the same as the above but 
 data: { "phonenumber": $("#phone").val()} as the data
I'd like to pass in "Email": 'Viewbag.Email' too

Comment: @MattHouser sorry that post above it to you.

Comment: @user2094139 I think the problem is that you're not blocking the default posting of the form (which does not include your email data).

Comment: @MattHouser Uhhh Pardon? I'm not actually sure what that means

Comment: When you click the button, it's `type=submit`, so it's going to submit your form.  You're trapping the click event, but not telling the form to not do a normal html post to submit it.  Try returning 'false' from your click event to block it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is of type `submit`.

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" value="Send"   id="sendMsg">Send</button>
```

By default, when the button is clicked, it's going to do a traditional HTTP POST to submit your form to your controller.

You have trapped the click event and added an Ajax call, however, you're not stopping the default form submit from happening.  I think you're seeing the form submission at your controller when you're seeing the null `email` value.

Try returning `false` from your click event:

```
$("#sendMSG").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
    return false;
});
```

This should prevent the form from submitting.

**Edit:**

Also, your button is called "sendMsg", but your hooking a click event to "sendMSG".  That's not going to work.  Case matters.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't grab the Email :( any other ideas?

Comment: In your comments and code, you're being very vauge about the action and controller name (eg. `/Controller/Action` and `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")` ).  Yet, in your code above, you name your action `ThankYou`.  Is your Ajax calling this `ThankYou` action, or something else?

Comment: oops. yeah i'm sure lol i've called them all properly

Comment: See my edit, I think that's the root of your problem.  You'll also need the `return false` to prevent the normal submit.  Your ajax was never executing.

Comment: love you so much. Thank you :D... nvm solved it. THANKS AGAIN!